# Best practice for URL's architectural Design in Django

Tags: python, design-patterns, django

I have been designing websites with Django for a while and I have also designed various sites. But here is a question that comes to mind at the beginning of any new project:

What is the best *URLs architectural Design* that creates both logical and meaningful URLs path as well as pluggable apps?

I will explain my question with a practical example.

**Practical Example And Problem**

Suppose that we have project with these features:

1. It has three applications called `Shop`, `Blog` and `Support`.
2. It has three URL section:

   2.1. Public section: that start with `/`.

   2.2. Consumer panel: that start with `/panel`.

   2.3. Administrator panel: that start with `/administrator`.

Each application has 3 views. For example Shop has: `public_shop_view`, `panel_shop_view` and `administrator_shop_view`.

Now, What is the best URL design for this project? I describe two possible answers here for URLs design.

**Solution 1:**

project/urls.py

```
path('', include('Shop.urls', namespce='Shop')),
path('', include('Blog.urls', namespce='Blog')),
path('', include('Support.urls', namespce='Support')),
```

Shop/urls.py

```
path('shop/', views.public_shop_view, name='public_shop_view'),
path('panel/shop/', views.panel_shop_view, name='panel_shop_view'),
path('administrator/shop/', views.administrator_shop_view, name='administrator_shop_view'),
```

Blog/urls.py

```
path('blog/', views.public_blog_view, name='public_blog_view'),
path('panel/blog/', views.panel_blog_view, name='panel_blog_view'),
path('administrator/blog/', views.administrator_blog_view, name='administrator_shop_view'),
```

Support/urls.py

```
path('support/', views.public_support_view, name='public_support_view'),
path('panel/support/', views.panel_support_view, name='panel_support_view'),
path('administrator/support/', views.administrator_support_view, name='administrator_support_view'),
```

---

**Solution 2:**
In this solution we create three apps (`Public`, `Panel`, `Administrator`) that just have `urls.py` file (to follow the interface strategy):

project/urls.py

```
path('', include('Public.urls', namespce='Interface')),
path('panel/', include('Panel.urls', namespce='Panel')),
path('administrator/', include('Administrator.urls', namespce='Administrator')),
```

Public/urls.py

```
from Support import views as support_views
from Blog import views as blog_views
from Shop import views as shop_views

path('support/', support_views.public_support_view, name='public_support_view'),
path('blog/', blog_views.public_blog_view, name='public_blog_view'),
path('shop/', shop_views.public_shop_view, name='public_shop_view'),
```

Panel/urls.py

```
from Support import views as support_views
from Blog import views as blog_views
from Shop import views as shop_views

path('support/', support_views.panel_support_view, name='panel_support_view'),
path('blog/', blog_views.panel_blog_view, name='panel_blog_view'),
path('shop/', shop_views.panel_shop_view, name='panel_shop_view'),
```

Administrator/urls.py

```
from Support import views as support_views
from Blog import views as blog_views
from Shop import views as shop_views

path('support/', support_views.administrator_support_view, name='administrator_support_view'),
path('blog/', blog_views.administrator_blog_view, name='administrator_blog_view'),
path('shop/', shop_views.administrator_shop_view, name='administrator_shop_view'),
```

**Now, What is the best practice? Solution 1 or solution 2 or other solution?**

Comment: 2nd one for sure. Each app's urls should be included in the urls.py in the settings.py folder.

Comment: Please answer to my question with your reasons @VisheshMangla

Comment: Django apps are reusable components. You can plug an app from one django project to some other django project.That is the idea and you should design an app in such as way.

Comment: Unfortunately CodeReview does not deal in hypotheticals. If you reform this into a stand-alone pet project to demonstrate your situation and show the code from beginning to end, it might become on-topic.

Comment: I think I have explained enough and written my codes so that my questions are part of the topic. @Reinderien

Comment: _Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site._ Your phrase _What is the best practice_, as well as the fact that none of your examples is complete (where do you import `path`?) bring this off-topic.

Comment: If you was Django developer you could understand that what is `path`! @Reinderien

Comment: It doesn't (and should not) matter whether your reviewers are familiar with Django or not. Relying on implicit knowledge and assumptions about your code will not allow for a high-quality review and will narrow the possible responses that you get. Your code needs to be runnable, period; rather than hoping that reviewers are able to fill in the blanks and read your mind.

Comment: Ok. I got that. Is it ok if I put all my codes here that can run? @Reinderien

Comment: Yes, absolutely :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @Reinderien

Comment: well, code related to frameworks cannot be runnable unless someone gives you the full repository. Even if someone gives you the repo you can't run it because everyone knows learning a framework is not a matter of few minutes.Therefore this question seems to be very much sensible and it is sufficiently clear for anyone who knows django well.

Comment: Code formatting is essential but in the time of formatters like black, and autopep8 do we really need code review to do that stuff?  Many answers on code review just correct a few indents and get the score whereas these kind of questions which in real are asking for best practices get shut.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you Vishesh @VisheshMangla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read the comments and am a bit torn by the discussion... yes, this code is not runnable; yes, you assume background knowledge; but you do that because 90% of Django starter code is not relevant to this discussion, but is essential to a Django project, so I think this is worth a shot.

For starters, it's worth pointing out that which of these solutions you choose *has no impact on the code you write*, since you will always refer to URL's by their name rather than by their path. This is solely a matter of beauty for how your capabilities are exposed to users and external services.

For this case, I would suggest a refactor that separates the front-end (paths) from the back-end (functionality). Have an app each for `support`, `blog`, and `store`, each of which implement their own models, serializers, utility functions, Celery tasks, etc. Then, have an app each for `panel` and `administration` that implements the paths, views, and user-facing logic about how people interact with those underlying concepts. You end up with some internal dependencies, but they're bipartite (only apps in the "frontend" group depend on only apps in the "backend" groups) and acyclic, so that's not a big deal.

If designed this way, you get the best of both worlds. You can keep the logical separation you show above among isolated logical components, but can use clean path construction and view implementation designed around how the users interact with your system. The downside is a larger number of apps and some internal dependencies, but those dependencies become explicit and you avoid the apps needing to implicitly know about each other and knowing how to avoid path conflicts.